# double Latex tags (Open and Close) multiple times in title Broke Math.stackExchange.com sorry!

Tags: feature-request, bug, mathjax, titles

Sorry, I made the title in one of my questions contain `$$ $$ $$ $$ $$ $$ $$ $$` and it broke the page here: [Possible new definition of Gamma (Euler-Mascheroni Constant): $\lim_{x \to 0} (-\ln ( \sqrt[x]{x!} )) = \gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953367/possible-new-definition-of-gamma-euler-mascheroni-constant)

It also makes line breaks appear in the title of the question on the Math SE home page.[image]

---

---

---

It seems to only break in Safari because too many redirects occur... just ran it on my mobile phone and it's working, but that might also just be because somebody edited the title to the correct state. (Whoever that was, thank you)

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really reporting a bug, but rather a designed feature of MathJax. Also, it certainly raises the question: why does someone enter a bunch of `$$ $$ $$` sequences in their question title?

Comment: @anorton But it shouldn't be allowed in the title of the question surly? I could fill the page with line breaks and make the home page require insane amounts of scrolling to get to the next question... ALSO, the bug is that when doing this it crashes Safari and won't load the web page due to `$$ $$    $$ $$    $$ $$` causing looping redirects.

Comment: @anorton: It is a bug that stackexchange allows user input to break the site. Even if the bug works via unexpected use of an intended feature of mathjax, that doesn't make it any less of a bug.

Comment: Why are double dollars allowed at all in titles? They completely break the layout of the page and are removed on sight by pretty much everyone. Surely it should be possible to ban their use in titles?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: possibly because double dollars are harmless for sites not using MathJax, and much of the underlying engine for SE is the same between the different sites.

Comment: I added the tag feature-request as, even if not considering allowing `$$` a bug, stripping it from user inputs in the titles is still a good idea and could be a good feature request.

Comment: @WillieWong Ah, I thought it was possible to ban things on a site-by-site basis (doesn't SO ban some words from their titles?).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I didn't mean to comment on its possibility. What I was trying to say is that because the SE engine was not designed from the get-go with MathJax in mind, there's no reason for them to disallow `$$` until someone points out there is a problem. And as far as I can remember, this may be the first time.

Comment: @WillieWong I see, good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been somewhat solved, at least as far as math.SE is concerned, where the use of diplayed (block) equations is no longer allowed in titles. More specifically, if you attempt to include `$$` in a title, you will receive the following error message:

[image: Title cannot contain "$$".]

which links to [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16946/8348).

The problem could still come up on other MathJax-enabled SE sites, however.